# debounce doesn't work with js scrollIntoView when behaviour:smooth

Tags: javascript, scroll, lodash

lodash's debounce function doesn't work properly when listening to scroll event that's caused by js native element.scrollIntoView

HTML

```
<nav>
<button id="btn1" onclick="goTo(1)">1</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="goTo(2)">2</button>
</nav>
<div id="el1">1</div>
<div id="el2">2</div>
```

JS

```
function goTo(x) {
 const elm = document.getElementById(`el${x}`);
  elm.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "start"
  });
  let func = _.debounce(() => {
    document.documentElement.scrollBy({
      top: -20,
      behavior: "smooth"
  })
}, 500)
  document.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
    func()
  })
}
```

Issue reproduction:
https://jsfiddle.net/do6bqfx7/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about `debounce`. See, `scrollBy` invoked in `func` is also a scroll - that's why it's handled by delayed call of `func` again, and again, and again. What you actually need is to make `func` an (effectively) single-time event handler. One possible approach ([**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/md8kzx20/)):

```
function goTo(x) {
  const elm = document.getElementById(`el${x}`);
  elm.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "start"
  });
  let func = _.debounce(() => {
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', func);
    document.documentElement.scrollBy({
      top: -20,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  }, 500);
  document.addEventListener('scroll', func);
}
```